# When did Hashim Amla get out for a duck in ODI?

Tags: statistics, cricket, trivia

I remember that Hashim Amla was leading the list of ODI batsmen, having played the most matches without a duck.

But now, he is not in the list, ie, he got out for a duck (I think it is his only duck in ODI history).

When did this happen?

Which bowler took his wicket?

Comment: He was also given out LBW about an hour ago in the practice match for Champion's Trophy, for a second ball duck, on the bowling of Junaid Khan.

Comment: @xylon97, quick update! but the question is about ODI which doesn't include warm-up matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He was out for a duck in a match against Australia. He was out for first ball duck in that match(c & b Bollinger). It was played at St George's Park, Port Elizabeth on 23 October 2011. That was the second ODI of the series which SA won by 80 runs.

Here is [the score card of that match.](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/514026.html)

**Update:**
He was once again out for first ball duck [in this match](http://www.espncricinfo.com/south-africa-v-pakistan-2013/engine/current/match/567371.html). Mohammad Irfan took his wicket.

Answer (score 3):

Hashim Amla, right handed batsman from South Africa, has been out for a duck (zero runs) quite a few times in this career, although less than very many batsmen. Here are the details..

In Test matches = 6 times (3 times vs India, 1 vs England, 1 vs Australia, 1 vs Pakistan).
In One Dayers = only once, vs Australia at Port Elizabeth on 23 Oct 2011.
In Twenty20s = only once, vs India at Colombo on 2 October 2012.

Answer (score -3):

In an ODI match against Pakistan, bowled by M Irfan at 0 runs. This was the series where Afridi made 88 on 48 balls.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to iDev's (updated) answer.